# Connection to the database terminated in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

Getting below error from neo4j while connecting via Java driver. It comes only when I try to create more than 50000 relationships in transaction. It is successful even in 30,000

```
Connection to the database terminated. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0.
```

I couldn't understand why its failing for 50000 records and its working for 30000 records. If there is some transaction size then the error could mention the same. Pleas help me to get around it

I'm using Neo4j Aura professional and java driver version is 4.1.1

Comment: Can you share the entire stack trace?

Comment: What kind of query do you use to create the graph? Do you do any batching?

Comment: I have 50,000 items and  create nodes and relationships for each. So there will b 50,000 queries in the transaction. I understand that no of queries are high but I get different error